# Cannot find Convert.ToInt32 method for using with .NET Standard

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to update project from `netcoreapp` framework to `netstandard` and looking for a way to replace conversion from object to int:

```
int value =  Convert.ToInt32(rawObject);
```

as [Convert](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Convert.cs) class is defined in CoreCLR, and cannot be used with .NET Standard framework.

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.1.0",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.1.0",
    "System.Reflection": "4.1.0",
    "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Thanks to @Lex-Li and @svick: Convert.ToInt32(object) method is really defined in the [System.Runtime.Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v1.0.0/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/ref/System.Runtime.Extensions.cs#L189) reference assembly. 
 In my case I had the following error even after updating dependencies:
`"The name 'Convert' does not exist in the current context".`

Deleting project.lock.json and restoring from scratch have solved the issue.

Comment: Would [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) do? You'd have to cast `rawObject` to a string first.

Comment: @ChrisF as a workaround can work.. but also need to think about edge cases like null

Comment: What do you mean "cannot be used"? What is the specific error you're getting? Also, are you compiling your code using VS or `dotnet` command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add System.Runtime.Extensions 4.1.0 to your `project.json`.

A quick search on the following site can show you why,

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Convert class is still unavailable

Comment: @Set show your project.json by editing the question. Meanwhile, use `System.Convert` if you forgot to use `using System;`.

Comment: have updated question. As I see in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System, there is only BitConverter class right now

Comment: @Set The right place to look is https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/ref/System.Runtime.Extensions.cs, which does contain `Convert`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles just fine for me with your project.json.

[Convert.ToInt32(object) is defined in the `System.Runtime.Extensions` reference assembly.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v1.0.0/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/ref/System.Runtime.Extensions.cs#L189)

Implementation assemblies for `System.Runtime.Extensions` forward the `System.Convert` to `mscorlib` (using `[TypeForwardedTo]`).